# Can we get to choose the application which can be used to edit a document in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, ios-extensions, uidocumentpickervc, document-provider

I was going through Document Picker & Document Provider Extensions of iOS8 today. Document picker allows us to pick documents of the different apps where as the document provider helps us to work with third party storage.

Right now I have one scenario that I am stuck with i.e, in my app I will have a document lets say a word document. Now I want to open this document in my app using an other app say Microsoft office and then I want to perform edit on this document. After editing, I should be able to come back to my application. Again if I view this document those changes should be present. Can this be achievable in iOS 8 without duplicating the documents.

Comment: @JohnSibly Nope John I didn't find answer to this.

Comment: ANy one found about this? Please help